# how do I modify a state without overwriting it

Tags: reactjs

I have a search bar, and once the user enters any word or words (eg: "green plant") I split those words with space and array would look like words = ["green","plant"]. Now, I need to use each word as a value to my filter api which indeed returns the data that has the search word in the title or name.

The issue is that, each time it calls it overwrites the existing state so that whatever data I got for word "green" is overwritten with the next api call for "plant".

My Code for setting them,

```
if (response.status === 200) {
  setProduct(response.data.product)
}
```

I also tried to use spread operators,
if (response.status === 200) {
setProduct([...product,response.data.product])
}

and also tried,

```
if (response.status === 200) {
  setProduct((prevProducts) => [
    ...prevProducts.product,
    response.data.product,
  ]);
}
```

Error for the above `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`

response.data.product:

```
[
    {
    "_id":"61daa6401d0f202659003c12",
    "name":"TIMA - Top Class Blanket",
    "originalPrice":1599,
    "storePrice":1500,
    "discount":6.2,
    "description":"Single Blanket , Size: 226*150 cm",
    "category":"blankets",
    "quantity":10
    },
    {
    "_id":"61daa6401d0f2026592eef3",
    "name":"Flora Bed",
    "originalPrice":2599,
    "storePrice":1500,
    "discount":7,
    "description":"Bed , Size: 226*150 cm",
    "category":"bed",
    "quantity":10
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the structure of product ? Can you show the line where you create product ?

Comment: @TheTisiboth hey, added in the question :)

Comment: thx! but can you also show the line where you create product, to see its type

Comment: From what I understand, product is an object, bout you would like an array of product ? Please describe more accurately what do you want to achieve, because it is not really clear to me

Comment: @TheTisiboth yes, product is a array of objects (products) and the initial would be a empty array. `const [product, setProduct] = useState([])`

Comment: and what is the result of this : setProduct([...product,response.data.product]) ?
Because it looks good to me

Comment: Or maybe you could show more of your code, maybe there is something wrong with your API call

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas Try this: `setProduct([...product, ...response.data.product])` As per your comment you are getting array of objects so there should be `...` before `response.data.product` to spread it

Comment: @TheTisiboth It just runs the first word

Comment: You get `TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance` because the initial state of your `product` is an empty array, whereas you're trying to use `prevProducts` as an object while trying to access the `product` field of the array `prevProducts`.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya I your case, first word is pushed twice

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas Then it seems like there can be an issue with your API response data. Please try printing out `response.data.product` and verify the data.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya The bottom of the question has the product structure. response.data.product would return a array of object. i.e array of product. Also edited the question, you can see the response.data.product in the bottom of the question

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example please ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely encountering a closure issue, where you are looping through the two API calls, but those get initialized with the same state A.
This would mean that when you want to update the state from A->B in the first call, then B->C in the second, what actually happens is that you get A->B followed by A->C, without the changes from B.
I recommend using the `Promise.all` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to `await` for all results, then set your state at once. If you really want to do it sequentially, then make sure to `await` the first one, set your state after it, then do the same with the second one. For this latter solution (not recommended), make sure to use the callback `setProduct((prev) => [...prev, newValue])`.

Comment: `setProduct((prev) => [...prev, newValue])` is giving me [Array(7), Array(3)] but pushing the objects to the first array